# WPF календарь: снять выделение с определенных дат

Tags: c#, wpf

Как снять выделение с определенных дат в обработчике `SelectedDatesChanged`?

Я прямо в этом обработчике из `SelectedDates` удаляю ненужные даты,
но визуально это не видно. Из коллекции нужные даты удаляются, но по прежнему остаются выделенными.

Может его как-то обновить можно?

**Добавлено:**

Задача проста: нужно снять выделение с определенных дат, причем список этих дат определяется по первой выделенной дате, т.е. все происходит в обработчике SelectedDatesChanged

Вот обработчик:

```
private void calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
//формируется deniedDates
    foreach (var deniedDate in deniedDates)
    {
        calendar.SelectedDates.Remove(deniedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то делаете не то. Приведите релевантный код.

Comment: А какой у вас `SelectionMode`?

---
У меня работает:

    <Calendar x:Name="Calendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange"
              SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged"/>

    void Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar.SelectedDates.Remove(DateTime.Today);
    }

Comment: хм.. у меня тоже самое не работает. SelectionMode да MultipleRange.

Comment: @nik604: А что возвращает у вас функция `Remove`? Проверьте. Выведите в лог `calendar.SelectedDates` до и после удаления.

---
А мой пример у вас работает? Конкретно с `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Remove удаляет из SelectedDates даты, тут все нормально.
Выше приведенный вами код не работает.

Comment: Не может быть такого в принципе. Вот вам полный текст проекта: http://pastebin.com/sZsNGyvm
Откомпилируйте его, выделите несколько дат и объясните, что выглядит не так.

Answer (score 1):

`NotifyPropertyChanged` выполняете после изменения данных?
Так же когда объявляете `ItemsSource`, там должен быть модификатор `Mode` равный `TwoWay`. Как то так `ItemsSource="{Binding ViewBooks, Mode=TwoWay}`.

Comment: Вообщем я биндингом там и не пользуюсь, просто удаляю вручную даты. Если просто удалить даты, то в целом все работает, но если удалять даты в обработчике SelectedDatesChanged, то даты все равно выделенные остаются...